# How did Casper the Ghost Die?

Tags: casper

How did Casper the Ghost Die? Outside of the 90's movie is their any explanation on how Casper and his uncles all died and what ever happened to his parents?

Answer (score 10):

Apparently, he's currently a ghost by nature, and [didn't die to get that way](http://casper.wikia.com/wiki/Casper_the_Friendly_Ghost):

> In the 1960s and 1970s, the stock answer provided by Harvey Comics in response to those wondering how Casper died was that he was a ghost simply because his parents were already ghosts when they were married.

Early comics did show Casper next to a gravestone with this name, and a fox was shown becoming a ghost after his death, which does imply that the original idea was that he became a ghost by dying, but the 90s film is the only place where a cause of death has been provided (namely catching pneumonia after playing out in the cold all day) and Harvey Comics has never contradicted themselves on him not actually being dead.

[Ferdie's Grave](https://youtu.be/NB2cJDq9rOY?t=8m11s)
[image: Ferdie emerging from his (labeled) grave in "There's Good Boos Tonight"]

Comment: Did the gravestone really have Casper's name on it? I thought it had the name of the fox (Lucky?).

Comment: Two separate incidents.

Comment: Got anything to prove that?

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd: No, I don't. All I have is the wiki, which states that early comics show him beside a tombstone with his name on it, and clips from the cartoon where the fox dies, where its name is on its stone.

Comment: If I could find my old Casper VHS tapes I'd help you out

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd: The animated short is available online. Still looking for a comic book image.

Comment: Ferdie! That's right! I knew it ended with an *ee* sound. Short for Ferdinand.